# Dividing a value which is in an Array

Tags: java, macos, netbeans-8

I am trying to divide the values in an array when the total has reached a certain limit.

So these are the array I currently have.

```
ArrayList<String> IDname = new ArrayList<>(); // this contains the name of the ID (Max. 10 names)
ArrayList<Integer> qty = new ArrayList<>(); // this contains the values acquired from user input (Max. 10 values)
```

What i am trying to do is once i have obtained a max input of paint per box, i am supposed to make sure that each ID in the array and their qty is in each box.

For example:
IDnames has ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4

weights has 343,274,199,197

max per box = 12

I want to make sure each box has at least each qty of the ID which is then displayed on a text field telling the quantities in each box and ID names

e.g:

Box 1 = ID1, qty, ID2, qty, ID3,qty ...

Box 2=....

How can this be done in code?

Comment: I don't really understand but I think map data structure is more appropriate. You can create a map which contain the idname and the qty.

`Map<String, Integer> box = new HashMap<>()`

You can store the pair of ID name and QTY in there and you then can loop the map and use the pair of key & value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood,
You can make something like this:

```
public void addPaint ( String id, Integer weight) {
       IDname.add(id);
       qty.add(weight);
}
```

which will add the values to both arrays and they will have the same index.
And if you want to show the values:

```
for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
            System.out.println(IDname[i]);
            System.out.println(weight[i]);
}
```

Comment: Or if you do not need to use arrays you can use what @Faris Arifiansyah said.